# Prove that for any $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, $[a,b]\sim[c,d]$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Is this proof valid? I'm not 100% sure.

${\textit Proof}$. The line with endpoints $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ is the diagonal of $[a,b]\times[c,d]$. The slope is $\frac{d-c}{b-a}$, so the equation of the line is $y=\frac{d-c}{b-a}x+b$ and we can solve for the y-intercept by substituting in $(a,c)$: $$c=\frac{d-c}{b-a}a+b$$ then $$b=c-\frac{d-c}{b-a}a=\frac{cb-ad}{b-a}$$ so we have a linear function $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]:x\mapsto\frac{d-c}{b-a}x+\frac{cb-ad}{b-a}$. Since linear functions are bijective, we have $[a,b]\sim[c,d]$.

Is it ok to conclude $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]:x\mapsto\frac{d-c}{b-a}x+\frac{cb-ad}{b-a}$? Since the line we are considering is the diagonal of $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, so the line has domain $[a,b]$ and codomain $[c,d]$; the part I was worried about was that is it clear that everything in $[a,b]$ actually maps to $[c,d]$.

Comment: If you want to be sure you can easily find the inverse function from $[c,d]$ to $[a,b]$.

Comment: What does your $\sim$ mean?

Comment: As it is currently written, the statement you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: @AnneBauval equinumerous, i.e that they have the same cardinality

Comment: Then yes your proof is fine, provided you assume $a\ne b$ and $c\ne d.$